# Could I have a user to write/read data to/from a google spreadsheet of *his* from a static website?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-authentication, serverless

I could not store any secret keys since the data would be accessed though a static website. (I dont want to use google forms)

I understand I need a secret api key if I want anyone to write/read data to/from a google spreadsheet that is mine, but this is not my case.

This for example about a simple "TODO app", where each user would just access their own data, do I still need a key if each user is accessing only their own private spreadsheed?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a broad question so my answer would be a series of recommendations, in that way you will have a better idea of what you have to do to fulfill your goal:

***1)*** First of all. If you haven't heard about [***Apps Script***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), I would recommend you to check it, because it integrates easily programming tools for all Google apps.

***2)*** Now knowing what's Apps Script, you could check how to integrate Apps Script code into your Spreadsheet by [***Extending Google Sheets***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets).

***3)*** [***Spreadsheet Service***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) allows performing several tasks related to your Sheet files.

***4)*** Knowing about Apps Script and how to handle the Sheets files by coding, the next step will be to check [***Web Apps***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app), which will help you to create an integrated web app on your Spreadsheet.

***5)*** The last thing I recommend you is to see the [***Class google.script.run (Client-side API)***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run), this class will pass values from your Front-end to your Back-end built on Apps Script.